# Operator new with nothrow option still throws exception

Tags: c++, exception, new-operator, nothrow

There is such code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for(;;){
        int* ptr = new (std::nothrow) int;
        if(ptr == 0){
            std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

However, this program still throws std::bac_alloc exception, altough new is called with std::nothrow parameter. This program is compiled in Visual C++ 2010. Why the exception is thrown?

Edit:

Using g++ on Windows from mingw, everything works ok.

Comment: This program should not compile. It's a pity it does. You should add `#include <new>`. Anyway, what version of VC++ are you using?

Comment: Well, it does . Version from 2010 year.

Comment: It also compiles on gcc. What the hell made me believe it would be a good idea to actually run it?

Comment: @pmr: You'd set `ulimit` to something small before running this, of course :-) Works fine, by the way.

Comment: Perhaps the << to cout is throwing.  What happens if you remove all the iostream stuff and `return` instead of `break`?

Comment: It works fine on ideone -- see http://ideone.com/gZK6F.

Comment: @fizzer: no change, it still throws exception

Comment: @scdmb: Try the code I posted to ideone. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your sample from VC2010. It is not new(nothrow) that throws, but [__security_check_cookie](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1854/Compiler-Security-Checks-In-Depth).

Comment: Hmm, that appear to be a compiler bug then.

Comment: The link is broken, please explain what was there

Answer (score 7):

`0` has to be formatted as `"0"`. That's going to take a few bytes; I'll bet that's the cause. Put a breakpoint on `std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc`  and you will know for sure.

Comment: Or put a try-catch block around the new thing and a try-catch block around the entire function to know if it really is the `new` that fails or not.

Comment: Even better, check the option to break on a C++ exception being thrown.

Answer (score -2):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kftdy56f.aspx) explains why it is still throwing and how you can make it not throw. It seems `nothrow` is just ignored.

> If you still want the non-throwing version of new for the C Runtime Library, link your program with nothrownew.obj. However, when you link with nothrownew.obj, new in the Standard C++ Library will no longer function.

I found an quite in depth article about this but it's kinda dated (VC 6) but maybe the problem still persists. BTW VC ignores all `throw()` specifications of functions.

[When Operator new(std::nothrow) Throws an Exception Anyway](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164087.aspx)

Comment: That page seems to talk about the "normal" `operator new` (`new X` as opposed to `new (std::nothrow) X`), whereas the question is specifically about the latter.

Comment: That refers specifically to the "regular" `new`. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevejs/archive/2005/11/01/487776.aspx for the explanation.